# System tests framework in Java

Tags: java, testing, system-testing

Looking for a framework for system testing in java. We have a web application running under tomcat (Spring, Hibernate, etc..) with a well defined API that can be easily exposed as RMI (or any other way).

We want to test this API. The framework should test the running server. The tests will be triggered by Jenkins or will run by the developers or QA Automation.

Most of the tests will be written by the developers, so that we want them to be similar to what they are familiar with (java, all above listed technologies). Performance testing ability is an advantage.

Any success/failure stories or tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Spring, Hibernate... - why not use [Spring integration testing support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html)?

Comment: What do you want out of a "framework for system testing" that you can't get out off JUnit/TestNG if you are doing RMI?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: because that's integration/unit testing and not really system testing on the target platform. In practice this is not an easy nut to crack (in my experience).

Comment: @ebaxt it's an option, to use just a "naked" JUnit or TestNG

Answer (score 1):

[Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/) is an **acceptance testing** solution. It uses wiki like test input and comparison  of HTML tabular data . You may able to tweak for your use. See [some info](http://www.beroux.com/english/articles/fitnesse-system-testing/)

Comment: I'm more interested in backend testing

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to test the API (which I'm assuming is Java code) I would recommend JUnit. It is the standard for unit / integration testing in the Java world. I would also look at a good mocking framework (EasyMock etc.) to see if that would be of use. If you are trying to do functional tests, I would recommend SOAPUI. Both tools will allow you to have test cases written by developers and can be triggered by Jenkins to execute and report test results.

Comment: As far as I can see, SOAP UI does not support RMI. Mocking is good for unit testing - in system testing the purpose is to test a real system

Comment: You had mentioned that you were able to easily expose your API as "any other way" which in my mind includes web services / http. If you are restricted to RMI, what more are you looking for than what JUnit can provide?